# Compatibility of maps on points under base change

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be an arbitrary scheme, and let $X,S'$ be  $S$-schemes.

Using e.g. EGA I (3.3.9), (3.3.14), one obtains for any $S'$-scheme $T$, viewed as an $S$-scheme via $S'\to S$, a canonical bijection of sets: $$f_X:Hom_{S'}(T,X_{S'})\cong Hom_S(T,X).$$

For any morphism $\varphi:X\to Y$  of $S$-schemes, let  $\varphi^*:Hom_{S}(T,X)\to Hom_{S}(T,Y)$ be the induced map  and let $\varphi_{S'}:X_{S'}\to Y_{S'}$ be the induced morphism of $S'$-schemes.

I suspect that the by $\varphi_{S'}$ induced map
 $$\varphi_{S'}^*:Hom_{S'}(T,X_{S'})\to Hom_{S'}(T,Y_{S'})$$
satisfies $\varphi_{S'}^*=f_Y^{-1}\circ \varphi^*\circ f_X$. In case this  is true, is there a simple way (which avoids working out all canonical maps involved) to see this?

Comment: Draw a diagram.

Comment: If you drew a diagram, you would see that the first bijection follows from the definition of a fibred product (no need to refer to EGA I, 3.3.9, 3.3.14), that what you call $\varphi^*_{S'}$ is just composition with $\varphi_{S'}$, and everything should be clear to you.

Comment: Dear Anon, thank you very much for your comments. Unfortunately, it is still not clear to me. Would it be possible for you to draw the diagram you mean in the answer box?